# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+n}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I'm currently studying calculus book and came across this problem:

$$ 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}} + ... +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+n}}\right)
$$

I think that it is needed to somehow represent the limit using integrals, however I don't know how exactly.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: Your expression between parenthesis is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+k}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tfrac{k}{n}}}$. This is the Reiemann sum with the uniform partition over the unit interval of  the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$, i.e. a Riemann sum that approximates the integral $\int^1_0\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x}}$

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew that I had to achieve the 1/n in the front but I missed that you can extract n from second square root and achieve Riemann sum. <3